# Ubuntu boot option disappear after bios update

Tags: windows, ubuntu, bios, uefi

It is a ThinkPad t490s laptop installed with windows 10 and ubuntu 16.04 dual boot.
When I use the windows, Lenovo has pushed some bios updates. But after the updating, the ubuntu can no longer be booted. It cannot even be seen from the boot options anymore.
How can I get the Ubuntu back?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it is nothing to do with Lenovo BIOS update.  Windows Update sometimes adds itself to the top of the NVRAM entries so it will boot straight into Windows rather than into your previous bootloader.

To restore grub (the default Ubuntu bootmanager) enter in an elevated command prompt in Windows:

`bcdedit /set '{bootmgr}' path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi`

Comment: That's not what is the issue. All boot options are gone simple because of a BIOS reset. No EFI image is in the list of Lenovo's UEFI.